# Position customAttributes on address-renderer

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom

I am using an [Address Fields Manager](http://docs.swissuplabs.com/m2/extensions/address-field-manager/) module.

The problem is that in the sidebar in the resume they are all seen together (address-renderer/ default.html) and I need to divide them:

```
<each args="data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
<text args="$parent.getCustomAttributeLabel(element)"/>
</each>
```

Is it possible to separate the CustomAttributes and position it where I want?

The same thing that is done in the Custom Address Template?

Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sorting the attributes in the backend?

[image]

Probably you can also access each attribute with something like: address().customAttributes.attribute

Answer (score 0):

yes, but it's not that.

In the onestepcheckout sidebar is everything inside the code

```
<each args="data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
<text args="$parent.getCustomAttributeLabel(element)"/>
</each>
```